# Converting this list like string without commas to list

Tags: python

I have this string:-

```
my_string = "[a:b][c:d][e:f]"
```

I wanted to convert this to a list like this:-

```
my_list = ['[a:b]','[c:d]','[e:f]']
```

Note that the elements of the lists are mere strings.
 However I tried these:-
`ast.literal_eval(my_string)` and `map(int,mystring)`.

Both of them return errors. 
Split command also returns this : ['[a:b][c:d]']. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain it better? What is the result you're hoping to get for a certain input?

Comment: Zach thanks for pointing the mistake out. I forgot to add [e:f]. Your previous answer worked.

Comment: @ZachP can you please repost your answer? That worked like a  charm

Comment: @Tania Undeleted. I thought you meant something more complex so I deleted it at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.findall` which will probably be as if not more efficient:

```
my_string = "[a:b][c:d][e:f]"

import re
re.findall("(\[.*?\])",my_string)
```

Output:

```
In [93]: r = re.compile("(\[.*?\])")

In [94]: my_string = "[a:b][c:d][e:f]"

In [95]: r.findall(my_string)
Out[95]: ['[a:b]', '[c:d]', '[e:f]']
```

Or use `str.replace` putting a space between the opening and closing then splitting:

```
In [101]: my_string = "[a:b][c:d][e:f]"

In [102]: my_string.replace("][","] [").split()
Out[102]: ['[a:b]', '[c:d]', '[e:f]']
```

Which is the most efficient:

```
In [103]: timeit my_string.replace("][","] [").split()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 445 ns per loop

In [104]: %%timeit         
s = '[a:b][c:d][e:f]'
l = s.split(']')
for i in xrange(len(l)):
    l[i] += ']'
del l[len(l)-1] #Th
   .....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 µs per loop

In [105]: timeit r.findall(my_string)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 962 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Add semicolon after each `]` :

```
my_string = "[a:b][c:d][e:f]"
my_string = my_string.replace("]", "];");
```

And then split it :

```
my_list = my_string.split(';');
```

Comment: This returns a string which needs to be split again to form a list. Also the last element needs to be deleted. Thanks for the logic though :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you ignored `[e:f]`?

Either way, it should be simple as the following solution:

```
s = '[a:b][c:d][e:f]'
l = s.split(']')
for i in xrange(len(l)):
    l[i] += ']'
del l[len(l)-1] #The last one will currently only be ']'
```

And that should get the wanted list.

Comment: Thanks for undeleting. This one is right on beam. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another variation with split:

```
my_string = "[a:b][c:d][e:f]"
changed = []
for i in my_string.split(']'):
     changed.append(i+"]")

print changed[:len(changed)-1]
```

Which gives:

```
['[a:b]', '[c:d]', '[e:f]']
```